# Automatically hide and show the dock is greyed out, how to reactivate the option?

Tags: catalina, dock

I have been using macOS Catalina since its  release but today the Dock suddenly refuses to hide. In the preference pane, the `Automatically hide and show the Dock` option is greyed out.

I have tried `killall Dock` which hides the dock for 1 second, then it comes back.

[image: Option Greyed out]

macOS details
OSX Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101)
Mac book pro 16" 2019

Comment: Have you rebooted the machine?

Comment: yes, it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a solution, thanks to [idownloadblog](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/02/14/auto-hide-dock-no-delay-mac/)

just put the code below into terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool true
```

It overrides the setting in preference